# Unresolved external symbol with Catch library

Tags: c++, unit-testing, build, cmake, catch-unit-test

I'm migrating some projects to use [CMake](https://cmake.org/) build system. Now I'm adding project with some unit tests using the [Catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch) library. It is header only library. The old **Visual Studio** project builds fine, but the new [CMake](https://cmake.org/) project gives unresolved external symbol linker error. I have defined **CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN** in one of my source files. There are added all **cpp** files from other projects which are needed for the tests and all libraries on which other tested projects depend are linked. Despite this I have unresolved external symbol error only with generated from [CMake](https://cmake.org/) project:

```
ChipCountTests.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Catch::SourceLineInfo::SourceLineInfo(char const *,unsigned int)" (??0SourceLineInfo@Catch@@QAE@PBDI@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl `anonymous namespace'::`dynamic initializer for 'autoRegistrar1''(void)" (??__EautoRegistrar1@?A0xb4291ec5@@YAXXZ)
1>FlyingChipRewardCalculatorUT.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Catch::SourceLineInfo::SourceLineInfo(char const *,unsigned int)" (??0SourceLineInfo@Catch@@QAE@PBDI@Z)
```

Obviously I'm missing to add some configuration from **vcxproj** to `CMakeLists.txt` but I'm currently can't figure it out.

Comment: You are missing some Catch library(s) obviously.  If you can't find them in the linker section of your VS project; then try looking in the headers of Catch for `#pragma comment( lib, "name-of-catch-library" )`  which will cause the named library to be automatically picked up by the linker.

Comment: @Richard Critten As I said the catch library is header only and there is no **libs** for it.

Comment: Did you use "official" instruction for CMake integration? https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/blob/master/docs/build-systems.md (see CMake section)

Comment: Could you please give a [mcve] including some `CMakeLists.txt` code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one of my files I have:

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include <catch.hpp>
```

but I also using **CMake** macro for adding precompiled header to the project:

```
add_precompiled_header (${TARGET_NAME}
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/StdAfx.h
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/StdAfx.cpp)
```

This macro forcefully includes precompiled header in all files, but in it I have `#include <catch.hpp>` without `#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN` which is needed by all files except one.

I added option to the macro to pass list of files in which not to be included precompiled header and this resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit hard to deduce a concrete problem from the context you provided, but [here](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/blob/master/docs/build-systems.md) is an official Catch instruction for CMake integration.

In my experience using it with Visual Studio - integration went smoothly.

Comment: +1 Thank you for pointing me to the official **Catch** documentation about **CMake** integration, but I didn't find there anything useful about my problem. Defining **Catch** as interface library and adding it as dependency in **target_link_libraries** is pointless because **Catch** is header only library and no separate build and linking are required. Nevertheless I tried it and this didn't change anything.

Comment: @bobeff Did you try to create a catch unit testing project in your new CMake environment *from scratch* using exact instructions? Maybe it will help you to find the exact problem, because currently there is not enough information. And doing it from scratch may help you to find a step where it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to use Catch with the Precompiled Header option enabled in my test project, I end up with linker errors LNK2019.

I still use stdafx.h in my project and disable the Precompiled header option in order for the project to build.

Right-click project -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++->Precompiled Headers -> Precompiled Header -> Not Using Precompiled Headers.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error and I solved it by linking the target to Catch2WithMain

```
target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_TEST} Catch2 Catch2WithMain)
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_TEST} PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_TEST} PROPERTY CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```